# How to edit html element with Javascript dom?

Tags: javascript

i try to edit the `span` element inside with javascript dom:

```
<div class="data">
<span>Jan. 16, 2019</span>
</div>
```

So that only last 4 characters are shown,

```
var list = document.getElementById("data");   
list.removeChild(list.childNodes[3]);
```

But it doesnot work

Answer (score 3):

One error: you're searching with `getElementById` for an element with **id** `data` but `data` is the **`class`**.

`<div id="data">` should make the list assignment work. Or use `document.querySelector('.data')`

The next line with `removeChild` makes no sense to me, at least with given HTML.

Answer (score 2):

In order to only keep the last four characters in the `span`:

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("data")[0];   
let str = list.childNodes[1].textContent;
list.childNodes[1].textContent = str.substring(str.length-4, str.length);
```

```html
<div class="data">
     <span>Jan. 16, 2019</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Last four characters: `str.substring(-4)`

Answer (score 0):

Two things are going wrong. You are looking for an ID, but the HTML does not have an ID. Also showing the last 4 characters is not going alright.

I would propose to add an id to the span:

```html
<div class="data">
   <span id="date">Jan. 16, 2019</span>
</div>
```

```
var span = document.getElementById("date");
var date = span.textContent;
span.textContent = date.substr(date.length - 4);
```